# Why is my SwiftUI @State variable null the fist time my sheet appears?

Tags: swiftui, null

In the view shown below there is a simple list of 3 items.  When the user selects an item in the list a sheet is presented showing the name of the item selected.  However, when I run it, the first time I select an item it shows "**item was null**".  If I select another item in the list it works perfectly.  If I go back and select the first item again, it now works.

Can someone tell me why the **selectedItem** variable is null the first time a button is clicked?

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var selectedItem: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                selectedItem = "Item 1"
                showSheet = true
            }, label: { Text("Item 1") })
            Button(action: {
                selectedItem = "Item 2"
                showSheet = true
            }, label: { Text("Item 2") })
            Button(action: {
                selectedItem = "Item 3"
                showSheet = true
            }, label: { Text("Item 3") })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Text(selectedItem ?? "item was null")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `sheet(item)`

Comment: I see what @loremipsum is saying.  [This article](https://www.swiftjectivec.com/swiftui-sheet-present-item-vs-toggle/) describes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you're going to need to use `.sheet(item:)`. The reason for this is that the common `.sheet(isPresented:)` is created before the button is tapped.

When using `.sheet(item:)` the string needs to be identifiable, but you can achieve that with a simple extension.
And now you also don't need the `showSheet` bool, because the sheet is now bound to `selectedItem`. Keep in mind that this means that `selectedItem` is set to `nil` when the sheet is dismissed.

An example of what this solution could look like for your code is as follows:

```swift
struct TestView: View {

    @State private var selectedItem: String?
    
        var body: some View {
            List {
                Button(action: {
                    selectedItem = "Item 1"
                }, label: { Text("Item 1") })
                Button(action: {
                    selectedItem = "Item 2"
                }, label: { Text("Item 2") })
                Button(action: {
                    selectedItem = "Item 3"
                }, label: { Text("Item 3") })
            }
            .sheet(item: $selectedItem, content: { item in
                Text(item)
            })
            }
            
        }

extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { return self }
}
```